# Execute list of SQL script files in Oracle SQLdeveloper(4.1.3.20)

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to execute list of SQL script files in SQLdeveloper, but it only executed only first line of statement.

**C:/runAll.sql**

```
@C:/sql/test1.sql;
@C:/sql/test2.sql;
@C:/sql/test3.sql;
@C:/sql/test4.sql;
@C:/sql/test5.sql;
.....
```

**Try 1**

At Oracle SQL Developer > File > open file >runAll.sql
Select all file list and press F5

**Try 2**

At Oracle SQL Developer > worksheet

```
@C:/runAll.sql
```

Try 1 and Try 2 does not work. It only executed only first line of statement(test1.sql). 
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

My findings using version 18.1...version 4.1 is from 2015, so you might want to consider [upgrading your software](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).

Remove the ';'s

This works

[image]

Something is running on your side.

Show us the output and any errors, or you're asking us to guess. This is my guess.

Comment: There was no error message, it just executed only one sql file.

Comment: @alice it should work with and without the ';'. If you select @C:/sql/test2.sql;' with your mouse and hit F5 - what happens?

Comment: Actually,  test1.sql of  end of line  'Exit' is written, that's why I cannot continue to execute test2.sql. Thanks you for help

Comment: @Alice that's why it's ABSOLUTELY CRITICAL that you share the actual code you're running when you ask questions. We could have helped you much sooner, and its' why i supplied a test case in my answer.